# How to pass array to AngularJS app via url using ui.router module

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I use Angular 1.5 and ui.router module  and want to pas int array to app throw url. www.example.com/#/filter?[1,2,5] or www.example.com/#/filter/[1,2,5] or something else.

```
.state('cats', {
             url: '/filter?catsIds', // or /filter/{catsIds}
             templateUrl:'cats.html',
             controller: 'catsCtrl'
         })
```

goal:

```
app.controller('catsCtrl',function($stateParams){
    console.log(Array.isArray($stateParams.catsIds)) // goal true
    ...
```

Comment: noticed your example url is using incorrect array parameter, try using commas e.g. www.example.com/#/filter?catsIds=1,2,5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't pass object through an ui-router parameter, I'd say while passing value make it `,` separated & then pass it.

So while calling state do something like below

```
$state.go('cats', { catsIds: [1,2,5].join(',') })
```

will form below URL

```
www.example.com/#/filter/1,2,5
```

While reading it from `$stateParams` do split that string by `,`

```
app.controller('catsCtrl',function($stateParams){
    console.log($stateParams.catsIds.split(','))
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the ui-router doc, one can actually pass an url parameter several time and it will be mapped as an array of values if the parameter is declared with 'array:true' in the routing configuration :

in your url :

```
www.example.com/#/filter?catsIds=1&catsIds=2&catsIds=5
```

will only work if your routing has :

```
{
  name: 'foo',
  url: '/foo/{arrayParam:int}`,
  params: {
    arrayParam: { array: true }
  }
}
```

See the doc for more information here : https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/1.0.19/interfaces/params.paramdeclaration.html#array